# Troubleshooting issue forks to make core version compatibility fixes

Tags: composer

During the Drupal 8->9 upgrade, we noticed an issue where module maintainers had abandoned a project or were not responding to merge requests in a timely manner. As you know, composer doesn't care about patches when it comes to compatibility with major versions of Drupal, so you need an actual release which is compatible with the next major version before you can update drupal core in composer. This problem was easily solved by using issue forks to make [core version compatibility fixes as per the article on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/git/using-gitlab-to-contribute-to-drupal/use-issue-forks-to-make-core-version-compatibility-fixes).

Now, for the 9->10 upgrade, I have yet to get this to work for some reason. I am wondering if anything has changed for the syntax we need to use, perhaps with gitlab or something.

For example, I have set my drupal repositories to ignore drupal/views_ef_fieldset and use the issue branch:

```
"repositories": {
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8",
            "exclude": [
                "drupal/views_ef_fieldset"
            ]
        },        
        "drupal/views_ef_fieldset": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://git.drupalcode.org/issue/views_ef_fieldset-3290466.git"
        },
```

Require line:

```
"drupal/views_ef_fieldset": "dev-3290466-automated-drupal-10",
```

I am fairly certail all of this is correct. Here is the issue branch:

https://git.drupalcode.org/issue/views_ef_fieldset-3290466/-/tree/3290466-automated-drupal-10?ref_type=heads

But I get this:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
> Problem 1
>
> - Root composer.json requires drupal/views_ef_fieldset dev-3290466-automated-drupal-10, found drupal/views_ef_fieldset[dev-1.x, 1.x-dev (alias of dev-1.x)] but it does not match the constraint.

Has the methodology for doing this changed since 9th?

Comment: FYI: For the Drupal 8 -> 9 upgrade there is a lenient composer [endpoint](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-drupals-lenient-composer-endpoint). For 9 -> 10 there is a lenient composer [plugin](https://github.com/mglaman/composer-drupal-lenient) to ignore the major version constraint.

Comment: Thank you @Hurdi. I think this is the best solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hudri mentioned, the lenient composer package is the right answer here. It is, actually, the new suggested method for dealing with these situations rather than pinning to a feature branch.

#### Documentation:

- https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches
- https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/upgrading-a-composer-based-site